# Unauthorised Bluetooth device keeps connecting to Mac

Tags: macos, security, bluetooth

Recently I started experiencing frequent random lags with a Bluetooth mouse I have connected to my iMac: the tracking speed would suddenly drop for a few seconds before returning back to normal.

One time, while it was happening, I quickly clicked the Bluetooth icon in the menubar to see what was happening, only to see some unfamiliar device with some random name presumably connected to my machine. It has no indication of what it is, only an option to *Disconnect*. My iMac is not set to be "discoverable" and I was never prompted to allow the connection with that device. It also seems to keep changing the name, so it's not always the same, but the symptoms always are.

I installed a bunch of Bluetooth monitoring tools, from the [Xcode dev tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode) page, and I am able to catch the activity of that random device (it keeps connecting every few minutes, but without any apparent pattern), but not identify the nature of that activity or find a way to stop it from happening.

How do I find the culprit (a human hacker or a rogue device somewhere in the building) and make it stop doing what it's doing?

[image: Active Bluetooth Connections]
[image: Bluetooth Explorer Event Log]
[image: Bluetooth Throughput]

Comment: Looks like Jenny's Notebook is trying to make contact. Maybe ask around for a Jenny within bluetooth range?

Comment: There is no one with such a device around. Also, now the name has changed to TODDLT.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After almost an entire day of experiments and investigation, I think I might have identified the nature of this strange behaviour. The biggest clue (and originally, the most concerning discovery, for obvious reasons) was the relation of the activity of those random devices, with almost 100% certainty, to **browser being open**.

That's right: the Bluetooth connections weren't happening unless I was actively working in the browser, navigating between pages. This was true for both Safari and Chrome (not Firefox however) but was **not** the case with Incognito/Private Browsing windows.

Bottom line: it appears that the issue was caused by misbehaving [Handoff](https://www.apple.com/nz/ios/whats-new/continuity/) feature and those random devices trying to connect could have been other people's iOS devices or Macs.

I have no knowledge of how Bluetooth and Bluetooth "sniffing" work, let alone the way Handoff makes use of those, so I can't say what exactly went wrong. By design, Handoff is supposed to only work between the Apple devices that use the same iCloud account, which definitely wasn't the case here.

For the time being, I simply turned Handoff off in the iMac's System Preferences, as well as performed a [factory reset of the Bluetooth environment](https://discussions.apple.com/message/13259024#discussion-13263724), just in case. I can't yet say if switching Handoff back on after the reset is safe, but will update this answer once I confirm that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Been having this strange behaviour lately and at first I was thinking my BT devices batteries were the cause. Then I got an Apple Trackpad and the issue didn't seem to affect that device like it did my other 3rd party devices. So I opened up the BT preference pane and saw a bunch of unsolicited device connection polluting that list. So long story short, over 5 years later and still relevant! Disabling Handoff sure did the thing, and thanks for sharing your findings with us! I feel a little more sane now ;)